# UUID to Integer Conversion for User IDs in Serverless App with DynamoDB - Any Better Approaches?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm working on a serverless application using AWS Lambda and DynamoDB. We have implemented video calling functionality using a third-party service. We use UUIDs as the global identifier for users in our app.

The Android SDK from this third-party service doesn't accept UUIDs as user IDs; it only accepts integers up to 2,147,483,647. This poses a limitation for us, as UUIDs are a better choice for ensuring uniqueness.

To address this, we've created a separate field called NumberId in our DynamoDB table. This NumberId is calculated based on the UUID. Specifically, we convert the UUID to a big integer and take the modulo 2,147,483,647. This ensures that the integer fits within the limits imposed by the SDK.

```
# Pseudo-code to convert UUID to NumberId
number_id = uuid_to_bigint(user_uuid) % 2147483647
```

While this method works for now, it has some downsides:

High probability of ID collisions as our user base grows (estimated to happen around 50,000 users).
We could check for existing NumberId during user creation, but this would make our serverless AWS Lambda function slower and less efficient over time as the user base grows.

We're using a serverless architecture, so traditional methods like sequential IDs are not a suitable choice.
I'm aware we could switch third-party services, but that's our last resort.

Is there a better approach to generate unique integers within the limit 2,147,483,647 that are compatible with our serverless architecture and DynamoDB?
Has anyone faced this issue and come up with a more scalable solution?
Thank you in advance for your insights!

Answer (score 1):

The most common way of handling this is to use a random number, coupled with using this number as a primary key in DynamoDB.  You'd generate the number:

```
int boundedInt = 
     new SecureRandom()
        .ints(-1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .findFirst()
        .getAsInt();
```

And then use this number as the primary key / partition key.  Don't check up front if the number is already in your DB - DynamoDB will tell you and you can generate another one.  That means that your insert code needs to be ready to retry a few times if needed.

If you really only expect ~50,000 entries this should be fast and the chance of collisions not terrible.